# How to sort keys only with same values?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, alphabetical-sort

For example, i have a dictionary:

```
Edern 38
Pellam 34
Ban 32
Lionel 30
Geraint 30
Brangaine 28
Erec 28
Guiron 28
Fisher 28
Elyan 28
Segwarides 26
```

In this case output will be:

```
Edern 38
Pellam 34
Ban 32
Geraint 30
Lionel 30
Brangaine 28
Elyan 28
Erec 28
Fisher 28
Guiron 28
Segwarides 26
```

i want to sort keys with the same values in alphabetical order, but don't touch elements with different keys? How to realize this?

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: How does one sort a dictionary? By definition, dictionaries are unsortable.

Comment: In dictionary, key is always sorted

Comment: @RPGillespie Use an `OrderedDict` https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @RPGillespie: Question title & body explicitly ask about sorting *keys*

Comment: Then the answer is clear: build a `list` of the keys you want to sort, then sort it.

Comment: Are you sure, you want to use dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary is necessary to save relations between values. But maybe it will be better to use arrays, so how to complete task this way?

Comment: @user3258741 What if there's `Foo 28` at the top of the list? Or all keys with same values are placed consecutively?

Comment: @Aerofoil Kite: you're wrong, [key order is not defined and can vary between versions of (C)Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict): "`Keys and values are iterated over in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you represent your name-number pairs as a list of two-item tuples, you can use `groupby` to clump similar-numbered items together, and sort each group internally without affecting group order.

```
import itertools

items = [
    ("Edern", 38),
    ("Pellam", 34),
    ("Ban", 32),
    ("Lionel", 30),
    ("Geraint", 30),
    ("Brangaine", 28),
    ("Erec", 28),
    ("Guiron", 28),
    ("Fisher", 28),
    ("Elyan", 28),
    ("Segwarides", 26)
]

result = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(items, lambda item: item[1]):
    result.extend(sorted(v))

print result
```

Result:

```
[
('Edern', 38), 
('Pellam', 34), 
('Ban', 32), 
('Geraint', 30), 
('Lionel', 30), 
('Brangaine', 28), 
('Elyan', 28), 
('Erec', 28), 
('Fisher', 28), 
('Guiron', 28), 
('Segwarides', 26)
]
```

...And if you really need these items in dict form, you can make an OrderedDict out of them, like so:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict(result)
```

Comment: style note: some users may prefer to `import operator` and use `operator.itemgetter(items, 1)` as the second argument to `groupby`. I constructed a lambda instead, merely because I like to keep my number of `import` statements low.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to sort by decreasing numeric value. So this should work for you:

```
d = {'Edern':38,
     'Pellam':34,
     'Ban':32,
     'Lionel':30,
     'Geraint':30,
     'Brangaine':28,
     'Erec':28,
     'Guiron':28,
     'Fisher':28,
     'Elyan':28,
     'Segwarides':26}

# build a dictionary that maps the numbers to all the keys that have that value
scored = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    if v not in scored:
        scored[v] = []
    scored[v].append(k)

for k in sorted(scored, reverse=True):
    for v in sorted(scored[k]):
        print("{} {}".format(v, k))
```

Output:

```
Edern 38
Pellam 34
Ban 32
Geraint 30
Lionel 30
Brangaine 28
Elyan 28
Erec 28
Fisher 28
Guiron 28
Segwarides 26
```

Of course, there's a one-liner for this:

```
for k,v in sorted(list(d.items()), key=lambda t: (-1*t[1], t[0])):
    print("{} {}".format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
Edern 38
Pellam 34
Ban 32
Geraint 30
Lionel 30
Brangaine 28
Elyan 28
Erec 28
Fisher 28
Guiron 28
Segwarides 26
```